# This switch statement is working with one Case how to make it multiple case Bison

Tags: bison

This switch statement is working with one Case how to make it multiple case

```
S: Statement {printf("ACCEPTED");}
```

Statement:SWITCH BRO ID BRC CBO E CBC

```
E: A 
 | A C




A: A B 
 | CASE DIGIT D 


B:  BREAK SEMI


C : DEFAULT D B



D : COLON ID SEMI

 ;
```

This is an issue i want to make grammar accepted with multiple cases 
[image]

Comment: yes this was typo but still not working

Answer (score 1):

Your grammar is terrible, and does not account for repetition of the CASE. You need to discover how to express lists of things. The general pattern is like:

```
item: ....
items: item
       | item ';' items
```

So we have:

```
case: CASE DIGIT ':' stmts
default: DEFAULT ':' stmts
cases: case | default | case ';' cases
```

You should also find out how you can trace the parser for debugging. With yacc, you can set the environment variable YYDEBUG and it will print a quite verbose of all parser states.

Answer (score 0):

Correct switch grammar
Don't need to use semicolon in between A E space will work.

Statement:SWITCH BRO ID BRC CBO E CBC

E: A 
   | A C 
   | A E

A: A B 
 | CASE DIGIT D

B:  BREAK SEMI

C : DEFAULT D B

D : COLON ID SEMI